# How to `echo` sql table data together with distinct column date?

Tags: php, database, mysqli, html-table

SQL Table `tbl_meals`

```
+-----+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------+
| id  | receiver|  bfast  |  lunch  |  dinner |   date   |
+-----+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------+
|  1  | smith   | served  |         | served  | 04-18-23 |
+-----+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------+
|  2  | philip  |         |  served | served  | 04-18-23 |
+-----+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------+
|  3  | mercede | served  |         | served  | 04-19-23 |
+-----+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------+
|  4  | annie   |         |  served | served  | 04-20-23 |
+-----+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------+
```

Supposing that a `connection` to the `database` `week_meal` is successful.
I need to display this in the HTML `table`.
The table should look like...

```
+---------+----------+----------+----------+
|   Date  | April 18 | April 19 | April 20 | and so on, until the last tbl_meals of each week
+---------+----------+----------+----------+
|Breakfast|   1      |    1     |  None    |
+---------+----------+----------+----------+
|  Lunch  |   1      |  None    |   1      |
+---------+----------+----------+----------+
|  Dinner |   2      |    1     |   1      |
+---------+----------+----------+----------+
```

I know it is quite complicated for me as a newbie in `php`, `mysqli`

I did only simple `$query` to display `DISTINCT` value from `tbl_meals` `date` column. It works fine only for the date which is

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT date 
        FROM tbl_meals 
        ORDER BY date ASC";
$res = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
```

But not the way it should be displayed.

```
+---------+----------+----------+----------+
|   Date  | April 18 | April 19 | April 20 | and so on, until the last tbl_meals of each week
+---------+----------+----------+----------+
|Breakfast|   1      |    1     |  None    |
+---------+----------+----------+----------+
|  Lunch  |   1      |  None    |   1      |
+---------+----------+----------+----------+
|  Dinner |   2      |    1     |   1      |
+---------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: You could take the results of your first query, and feed them in to three subsequent queries for breakfast, lunch and dinner.  For example, `SELECT MAX(IF(date = '04-18-23', bfast, NULL)) AS "April 18", MAX(IF(date = '04-19-23', bfast, NULL)) AS "April 19", ... FROM tbl_meals GROUP BY date` will get you the data for the 'breakfast' row

Comment: @RobEyre - The `date` = `'04-18-23'` is not constant. It will be changed as week changed. Is there any way that will make the date flexible?

Comment: That's what I was suggesting.  You use the results of your first query when you're contructing the others.  So loop through the distinct dates you've got, and build up your next SQL query dynamically

Comment: @RobEyre - Did I do it right? `$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT date FROM tbl_meals ORDER BY date ASC";
$res = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
foreach($res as $row) {$bfquery = "SELECT MAX(IF(date = $res, bfast, NULL)) AS $res FROM tbl_meals GROUP BY date";
echo $row['bfast'];}`

Comment: What else have you tried to resolve the problem? The code you've shared doesn't contain any HTML table

Answer (score -3):

```
// adapt to your needs
$startDate = new DateTime('2023-04-18');
$finishDate = new DateTime('2023-04-25');

// we need to convert a string (mm-dd-yy) into a MySQL DATE (yyyy-mm-dd)
$datesWhere = ' WHERE CAST(CONCAT(' .
    // year (plus separator)
    '"20", SUBSTR(`date`, 7, 2), "-", ' .
    // month (plus separator)
    'SUBSTR(`date`, 1, 2), "-", ' .
    // day
    'SUBSTR(`date`, 4, 2)' .
    ') AS DATE)' .
    sprintf(' BETWEEN "%s" AND "%s"', $startDate->format('Y-m-d'), $finishDate->format('Y-m-d'));

// first we retrieve the distinct dates (within the date range)
$sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT `date`' . 
    ' FROM `tbl_meals`' .
    $datesWhere .
    ' ORDER BY `date` ASC';

$res = mysqli_query($connection, $sql); 

// use the distinct dates as table column headings
// and also use them to contruct the columns of our next SQL statement
$select = [];
echo '<table>';
echo '<thead><tr>';
echo '<th>Meal</th>';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    echo '<th>' . htmlspecialchars($row['date']) . '</th>';
    // we will count the number of non-NULL columns for this date
    // NB leaving '%s' in the string for later sprintf() substitution according to which meal
    $select[] = sprintf('COUNT(IF(`date` = "%s", `%%s`, NULL)) AS "%s"', $row['date'], $row['date']);
}
echo '</tr></thead>';

// aggregate SQL statement - one column for meal name, then our date columns
$sql = 'SELECT "%s" as "Meal", ' . implode(',', $select) .
    ' FROM `tbl_meals`' .
    $datesWhere .
    ' GROUP BY `date`';

// make three versions for the three meal types
$bfastSQL = sprintf($sql, 'Breakfast', ...array_fill(0, count($select), 'bfast'));
$lunchSQL = sprintf($sql, 'Lunch', ...array_fill(0, count($select), 'lunch'));
$dinnerSQL = sprintf($sql, 'Dinner', ...array_fill(0, count($select), 'dinner'));

// join them together so that we get three rows in our result set
$mealsSQL = $bfastSQL . ' UNION ' . $lunchSQL . ' UNION ' . $dinnerSQL;

$res = mysqli_query($connection, $mealsSQL); 
echo '<tbody>';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    echo '<tr>';
    // the first item is the meal name
    echo '<th>' . htmlspecialchars(array_shift($row)) . '</th>';
    // the remaining items are the values by date
    echo '<td>' . implode('</td><td>', array_map('htmlspecialchars', $row)) . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</tbody></table>';
```

Comment: I haven't run this - you'll have to test it and adapt to your needs

Comment: an error in your SQL syntax on line 113 which is ```$sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT date' . 
    ' FROM tbl_meals' .
    sprintf(' WHERE date BETWEEN "%s" AND "%s"', $startDate, $finishDate) .
    ' ORDER BY date ASC';

$res = mysqli_query($connection, $sql); ``` The error occurs inside query `$res`

Comment: @RobEyre If `04-18-23` is the date format then `between` won't work as these are strings, not dates.

Comment: @RobEyre - The edited answer you have provided returned one `date` column. Breakfast in `NULL`, Lunch is `lunch` and Dinner with `dinner` output. Not returning a number or a total number, instead.

Comment: @Jephoy is your date column a string or a datetime?

Comment: I'll comment out the WHERE clause for now, pending clarification on this

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Also, share why you didn't use prepared statements to make the code a bit more secure

Comment: I also switched the aggregation to COUNT, to show the number of non-NULL entries (guessing that is what your intention is)

Comment: @RobEyre - Date is a string. not a datetime

Comment: OK, that's going to make date restrictions a bit more tricky.  Apart from this, does the code in the answer give you what you want?

Comment: @RobEyre - the edited codes were almost perfect, but there is I think a little editing to be done. I have saved a photo here [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XXsJVsMP4j6MLFdKS3lOwAoRIYzmLrW4/view?usp=share_link). Kindly check.

Comment: Please can you echo the value of $bfastSQL?

Comment: @NicoHaase, no need for prepared statements since I just need to `echo` the `values` from `tbl_table`. Inserting values using prepared statements were already done.

Comment: **Selecting** data with a `WHERE`  condition that contains unsanitized data might also need a prepared statement

Comment: I've adapted the answer to do date range checking (untested), working on the assumption that your date strings are all mm-dd-yy.  I've also added a few more comments describing the code.  There's no user-generated content here, but if you want to convert the database calls to prepared statements, that should be fairly straightforward.  If it is still buggy, please add a comment and I'll see if I can fix it